# Is there a way to use more than one target namespace in a single XSD file?

Tags: xsd

I know I can create separate XSD files for different target namespaces and `import` one file into the other in order to declare elements from a foreign namespace; but is there a way to have all elements declared in a single XSD file? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no, there is no way to do such a thing.

Comment: If that's the way it is, than that's the way it is ... Thanks for your answer.